# Optimize Mysql Query Having count and Group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple mysql table which has around 12 million records.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS md5_table(
    md5 char(32),
    category INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (md5),
    INDEX INDEX_MD5(md5)
 );
```

I want to count category from the above table.

```
SELECT category, count(category) FROM md5_table
GROUP BY category;
```

We are using this query frequently, and it took around 10 sec to execute. I want to reduce it down to milliseconds.

Comment: You should put an `index` on the `category` field to make it faster.

Comment: Put index and it will be faster

Comment: but we are also frequently inserting the row in table and also updating the category column, Index category column make it slow for Update?

Comment: Your choice = (you want faster query = need index, you want faster inserts = less indexing). Only you can test the real world impact in your database. We can only give generic advice.

Comment: I think no problem, but if you do huge amount of delete/insert/update, you should OPTIMIZE/ANALYZE TABLE.

Comment: @dwir182 can you explain a little more about your suggestion?

Comment: Yes, index will make each update effectively two updates, but highly unlikely this will outweigh your query performance. No question that to answer your issue that an index will be the only way to go.

Comment: ok let me do a couple of test with indexes and share the results of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.  Assume you have a `category` table.  Then try:

```
SELECT c.category,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM md5_table t
        WHERE t.category = c.category
       ) as cnt
FROM category c;
```

This requires an index on `md5_table(category)`.

I find that MySQL is rather finicky in using indexes for aggregation queries.  You might find that this method speeds your particular query.

Comment: We are also frequently inserting the row in table and also updating the category column, Index category column make it slow for Update?

Comment: @AqeelHaider . . . The index will also need to be maintained.  This will add overhead to inserts and updates.  Unless you are in a high-transaction environment, this probably won't have a visible effect.

Comment: @Gordin Liniff can you explain a little more on Index maintained point or point me to the right direction.